# Clauses have differing numbers of arguments (when mixing impossible pattern and effects)

Tags: idris

Take the function `tail` as in the list library:

```
tail : (l : List a) -> {auto ok : NonEmpty l} -> List a
tail []      {ok=IsNonEmpty} impossible
tail (x::xs) {ok=p} = xs
```

Now try to replace the output type with an effectful computation:

```
randomIndex : (l : List a) -> {auto ok : NonEmpty l} -> Eff Nat [RND]
randomIndex []      {ok=IsNonEmpty} impossible
randomIndex (x::xs) {ok=p} = pure 0 -- whatever
```

And you get the error `Clauses have differing numbers of arguments`.

This seems wrong. Does anyone know why this happens? Is it possibly because `Eff` is a type synonym for some function type?